# python: loadmat - ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed

Tags: python, scipy, mat

Trying to read a matlab file into python. I am using the function `loadmat` from `scipy.io` to read it, and I'm getting back the error `ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed`.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It probably depends on file contents..

Comment: Do you know anything about the file contents?  What was saved from the MATLAB session?  It might also help to see the traceback - where the error occurred.  I've never seen this error message in this context, so can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I found out that this was a binary file (was written with `fwrite`). So this was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this was a binary file (was written with Matlab's `fwrite`).
The solution was saving the file as text, and then loading it in python not using `loadmat`.